# Adding permanent routing

Tags: ubuntu, startup, route

Each time when I start my computer I type in the console

```
sudo route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.240.0 gw xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

When computer is rebooted or switched Off/On I must re-enter this in the terminal.

Is there an option whit which I can add this route permanently? I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `route` entry to your `/etc/rc.local` file (before `exit 0`):

```
/sbin/route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.240.0 gw xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

or add it to your `crontab`:

```
@reboot /sbin/route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.240.0 gw xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

Use the absolute path to `route` executable, on my system `/sbin/route`, change if needed.

As a side note, start using the `ip` command (`ip route ....`) for these trivial tasks now as the utilities of `net-tools` package are deprecated now.

Comment: Thank's a lot. It's working perfectly. With IP how will look this? Just IP instead ot route... ?

Comment: ip is a new command (in /sbin usually) which has all of the previously separate ip related commands (e.g. route) as subcommands.  So this would be "ip route ..." to replace the direct call to route.  In practical terms, add three characters "ip<space>" after the second slash.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on heemayl's answer regarding the use of the`ip` suite.

The correct command to put into `/etc/rc.local` is

```
/sbin/ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/20 via yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/20` represents the network address **and** the netmask (240<sub>10</sub>=11110000<sub>2</sub>), so 20 bit are set, that number is now called *prefix*, and `yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy` represents the gateway.

Your `/etc/rc.local` should look this way:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/sbin/ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/20 via yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
exit 0
```

It is important to leave `exit 0` in place as the last line.